# Newbie question about editing vertex maps

Tags: blender-osm

I created this vertex map by selecting and assigning them in edit mode. Can you suggest a method to obtain a sharp edge without the gradient from red to blue. I’m trying to use this vertex map for a particle system to make fur. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Vertex weights (which is what it looks like you're talking about) are not a property of faces, but a property of vertices.  The vertices *are* assigned to the exact numbers you specified, but in order to help you visualize this, gradients are drawn across the faces.  These gradients don't actually exist.  Simply put: you can't get rid of apparent vertex weight gradients.  If you want finer control, you need to either create more vertices, or else use an image texture to control the particle characteristics.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understood most of it, but can you please explain how an image texture can be used to control particle characteristics?

Comment: That's a new question.  Do your research first, then if you can't find anything, ask a new question on SE.